# Why do I get 1 hour ahead of a column in postgres database?

Tags: java, postgresql

I save the current date and time of the day in a postgres database with `LocalDateTime.now()`. The column type is set to `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`. When I access this data, I see that it is 1 hour ahead. I have recorded the date at **15**:18, in the database it is **14**:18.

I would like this to be the local date so that I can read the dates in the database more easily.

On which side should I correct the problem? On the java side? on the database side? Should I use timezone?

Comment: Postgres stores everything at timezone UTC.

Comment: Don't include pictures of text in SO.

Comment: In my opinion I think you should fix the problem in the java code not in the database side (yes, every choice contains advantages and disadvantages) for many reasons:

Solving the problem in java file will ensure that the date and time are stored and retrieved with the correct time zone information.

However, if you want to solve the problem in the database side then you may face a problem doing that in the server side when you deploy the database moreover every country have deferent time zone so I think tracking, store and retrieve the data will not be in that efficiency.

Comment: Using TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE would avoid the entire issue, just use the time zone you'd like to use and you will be fine.

Comment: @BjarniRagnarsson **Incorrect.** What you say is true for columns of type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. But here the Question states their use of a different type: `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.  This latter type stores only a date and a time-of-day. No offset or time zone involved. Saying this column stores at UTC is incorrect as the concept of UTC is non-existent, irrelevant.

Comment: Timestamp with timezone stores only the UTC.  It doesn't store the timezone.  It accepts timezone as input and converts accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

## Time zone implicitly applied

Be aware of time zone involvement. Your line with `LocalDateTime.now()` implicitly applies the JVM’s current default time zone in capturing the current date and current time. Verify the value returned is actually what you expect; do not assume.

> so that I can read the dates in the database

How exactly did you read the value stored in the database?

If you executed Java like this:

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

… then you will indeed get back the exact value you stored.

If, on the other hand, you used a tool like *psql* or *pgAdmin*, be aware that many such tools have an anti-feature where they **inject a current default time zone** *after* retrieval and *before* returning the value to you. The anti-feature is well-intentioned, but creates a false illusion.

You neglected to describe your exact operations. So I cannot provide a more specific explanation. If you rewrite your Question with details, I may be able to refine my Answer.

## Moment

You said:

> I save the current date and time of the day in a postgres database with LocalDateTime.now(). The column type is set to TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE

Don’t.

You are using the wrong data types.

You need to change the data type in the database. And you need to change the data type in Java.

I cannot imagine a scenario where calling `LocalDateTime.now()` is the right thing to do. That class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, as the class purposely lacks the context of a time zone or offset from UTC.

To record a moment, define your column as the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. Any time zone or offset info you provide with an input is (a) used to adjust the date and the time to an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds, (b) then discarded. So values stored and retrieved from columns of this type are *always* in UTC.

Capture the current moment in Java. Notice how I passed a specific offset rather than relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Write to the database in a column of the type `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

Retrieve from the database.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

If need be, adjust to a particular time zone of interest. Same moment, different wall-calendar/clock.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

If using tools other than your own Java code, be aware of their having a time zone injection anti-feature as discussed above. You may want to set the tool’s current default offset/zone to zero, to UTC.